# Trying to login using requests but the fields are dynamic

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to log on this site requests using the library but the fields have dynamic id like:

```
<input id="df76922e-dd08-40bf-bc99-94bb7f67f10b.loginForm.username" maxlength="50" name="df76922e-dd08-40bf-bc99-94bb7f67f10b:username" value="" tabindex="1" class="mail inpRad" type="text">
```

And this is my code:

```
import requests

payload = {'?????': email, '?????': senha}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
           'Accept': '*/*',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

request = requests.post('"https://carrinho.submarino.com.br/CustomerWeb/pages/Login'
                     headers=headers,
                     data=payload)

print(resquest.text)
```

Is possible to do login using requests o any other library?

This **df76922e-dd08-40bf-bc99-94bb7f67f10b** change every request, but **loginForm.username** is static.

Comment: i recommend mechanize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's just one dynamic field, you can also use regex to get it:

```
import requests
import re

r = requests.get('https://carrinho.submarino.com.br/CustomerWeb/pages/Login')
m = re.search('id="(.*)\.loginForm\.username', r.content)
id = m.group(1)
payload = {id+':username': email, id+':password': senha}
```

Comment: But... at next request this not will change again?

Comment: this imitates your browser session -- visiting the page and submitting the form. so this is the correct value for the next request

Comment: When i print the payload i get:

'id="0d607bb4-3b7c-4295-901c-b95cfcb78c71.loginForm.username:username': '', 'id="0d607bb4-3b7c-4295-901c-b95cfcb78c71.loginForm.username:password': ''

but would not that be?

'i"0d607bb4-3b7c-4295-901c-b95cfcb78c71.loginForm.username': '', '"0d607bb4-3b7c-4295-901c-b95cfcb78c71.loginForm.password': ''

Comment: sorry i meant to use `m.group(1)` instead of `m.group(0)`

Comment: Thanks, works!first step would be to make the request again with payload?

Comment: <HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Invalid URL</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Invalid URL</H1>
The requested URL "&#47;CustomerWeb&#47;pages&#47;Login", is invalid.<p>
Reference&#32;&#35;9&#46;269d9fc9&#46;1453959943&#46;aa6607c
</BODY></HTML>

=/
Can you see the code on pastebin to check what is wrong?

Comment: just checked the login page source, looks like the form contains many hidden fields, which are required in the request. i see 2 strategies: 1) open developer console and log the network request for the login request, and imitate it in python `requests`, or 2) use `mechanize`, which conveniently does the imitation for you.